# Run once then repeat a script

Tags: jquery, arrays, onload

I've written the following which successfully repeats the script in 5 second intervals. However, I'd like it to start without a 5 second delay. Is ti possible to run the script once without the delay, then start it?

```html
<body onload="Run()">


 
<p id = "Text" style =
    "text-align:right; font-size: 100%; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; color: black; font-family:poppins;">
</p>
 
<script>
 
    var down = document.getElementById('Text');         
    var arr = [
      "\"The end of the liver and the beginning of reading.\"",
      "\"The most straight geniuses intent lemur sand,\"",
      "\"Passim abandonment to fashion,\"",
         
              ];
     
     
 setInterval(function Run() {
        down.innerHTML =
            arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
  }, 5000) </script>
```

Comment: What is the specific issue? Please include a snippet of code; much easier to diagnose problems with context. It should be a process of getting a random integer 0-(array length - 1) and inserting the string into the DOM.

Comment: thanks @DaveNewton I've upadted with code. It seems to be working but it seems a bit off?

Comment: *"but it seems a bit off?"*: how so?

Comment: @trincot Well, I'm trying to make this repeat every 5 seconds using SetTimeout but I can't adapt it. Feels like what I've done isn't adaptable.

Comment: That isn't what the question is saying. Please update the question with code that reproduces your problem?

Comment: @trincot sorry, I hadn't clicked the jquery snippet button. Question updated.

Comment: Did you try with `setInterval`? What was the problem when you tried? Can you show (in your question) the *problem* you encountered? NB: there is no jQuery in your code.

Comment: @trincot, apologies, I've edited the original with the correct code.

Comment: The script now has syntax issues: you close a parenthesis, when there is still a brace open, and you close that brace after the closing parenthesis. You should carefully pair braces and parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, if I interrupted your little cat and mouse game here ;-)

The following snippet contains a few corrections that will make the script work:

- I defined the function `Run()` independently of the `setInterval()` call
- and then I refer to it as the callback function for `setInterval()`.

```js
function Run() {
 down.innerHTML=arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]; }  
const down= document.getElementById('Text');         
const arr = ["hello","goodbye","and whatever","I wanted to say"];
        
setInterval(Run,5000);
```

```html
<body onload="Run()">     
<p id = "Text" style =
    "text-align:right; font-size: 100%; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; color: black; font-family:poppins;">
</p>
```

In SO snippets the `<script>` portion will always be called *after* the HTML section has been loaded. This is of course something you must make sure in your own document structure. The easiest way to achieve that would be to place the `<script>` section *after* your `<body>`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've accepted your answer as I hadn't seen it before re-editing the question.